# Retrieving an Enum through a class and its descendants

Tags: c#-4.0, reflection

I have a class that I've defined, and I have a number of child classes derived from it. The parent class has an enum (let's call it 'Barf'). Each descendant ALSO has an enum with the same name but not the same values. What I'm trying to figure out how to do is write a method in the ancestor class that gets the version of Barf for the actual class of the instantiated object. So if I create an instance of Ancestor, I'd like to have this method process the entries for Ancestor.Barf . If I create an instance of one of the child classes of Ancestor, I'd like to have the method process Childx.Barf values.

Obviously this is going to be a Reflection solution, but my reflection skills are pretty sparse. Any help?

Comment: This is probably possible with reflection, but it seems like code smell (programming based on the source-code name of an enum, which is - and should be - basically arbitrary). Why not put all possible values in the enum and make an abstract method like `public abstract IEnumerable<Barf> GetBarf()`

Comment: That doesn't feel right. Thought about it, but it means that every time I add a descendant I have to potentially go modify the base class.

Comment: Not if you keep your enum in its own class. Either way, I still think that's highly preferable to using reflection for this. There are other wa It's an interesting question, but more for the "can I" aspect than the "should I".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the fun of it, here is a possible approach:

```
public class Ancestor {
    public enum Caffeine {
        Tea,
        Coffee
    }

    public void ProcessValues() {
        var type = GetType();
        var nestedEnums = from t in type.GetNestedTypes()
                          where t.IsEnum
                          select t;
        var nestedEnum = nestedEnums.Single();
        foreach(var val in Enum.GetValues(nestedEnum)) {
            Console.WriteLine("Drinking {0}", val);
        }
    }
}

public class Descendant : Ancestor {
    public new enum Caffeine {
        Jolt,
        RedBull
    }
}

// The following prints:
// Drinking Jolt
// Drinking RedBull
Ancestor x = new Descendant();
x.ProcessValues();
```

Of course, you could achieve the same thing using polymorphism:

```
public class Ancestor {
    public enum Caffeine {
        Tea,
        Coffee
    }

    protected virtual Type GetNestedEnum() {
        return typeof(Ancestor.Caffeine);
    }

    public void ProcessValues() {
        var nestedEnum = GetNestedEnum();

        foreach(var val in Enum.GetValues(nestedEnum)) {
            Console.WriteLine("Drinking {0}", val);
        }
    }
}

public class Descendant : Ancestor {
    public new enum Caffeine {
        Jolt,
        RedBull
    }

    protected override Type GetNestedEnum() {
        return typeof(Descendant.Caffeine);
    }
}
```

As Justin Morgan has pointed out however, having the need for such a construct may be an indication of an underlying design issue in your code.

Comment: Thanks for that. Even if I end up finding a better design codewise, examples like you gave are educational -- never a bad thing. As to my design, yeah I'm not happy with it and I'm still trying to come up with something better. I'll go with the enum descendants if I just can't come up with anything else.